# Check if a cell contains a word

Tags: excel, vba

If any cell in column A contains the word Training- then do nothing, if not add the word Training- before text already in a cell

I'm working on a macro to run through column A in a single sheet, and can't quite figure out how to check if a cell contains a word in an if statement or something of that nature. Column A has a formula to generate unique ID's. The current setup I have adds the word, but if ran more than once will duplicate it into the cells.

The code I'm working on now:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 2 Then 'This is the column that causes the ID to be created
'This uses the target offset so it assumes in two spots below that the column to update is "A" and
'that the column is one position to the left of the target column above
    If Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
       Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A")) + 1
    End If
End If

End Sub

Function Max_Each_Column(Data_Range As Range) As Integer
    Dim TempArray() As Double, i As Long
        If Data_Range Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        With Data_Range
        ReDim TempArray(1 To .Columns.Count)
        For i = 1 To .Columns.Count
            TempArray(i) = Application.Max(.Columns(i))
        Next
    End With
        Max_Each_Column = TempArray
End Function

Sub AppendToExistingOnLeft()

For Each cell In Range("A1:A1000000")
If cell.Value <> "" Then
If Not cell.Value Like "Training*" Then cell.Value = "Training-" & cell.Value
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Not cell.Value Like "Training*" Then cell.Value = "Training-" & cell.Value` :D

Comment: @2acb_John_Suren Don't post code in a comment, add what Maciej Los suggested to your original question and indicate it as a solution